# Bootstrap 3.1.1: I can't import all the bootstrap .js files, how is "= require" supposed to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the latest Bootstrap v3.1.1 Sass.

Within the .zip file, I get 
lib, tasks, templates, test and vendor.

I ignored everything and only use the vendor > assets folder.
The assets folder has all the fonts, stylesheets and javascripts I need.

I have gotten the file structure setup properly. 
However when I am trying to import .js files from the javascript folder, I am having a bit of a problem.

Unlike the bootstrap.scss file that comes along. I can just uncomment the _.scss file that I need and it will work.

Within the bootstrap.js file, it contains some syntax that I haven't seen before. After a bit of Google, it says 'require' is a nodejs syntax.

[image]

I uncommented a few and try to see if they work. However it fails. the .js file I got back is exactly like the above screenshot. It doesn't concatenate modal.js, tooltip.js and popover.js. I did abit of Google, it says I need to have RequireJs?

Comment: I don't think you understand Node.js... Node.js doesn't have a DOM, and bootstrap serves no purpose in backend code.

Comment: @tsturzl yeap, I don't understand node.js I only use it to setup my frontend. By the way, you know the solution to my problem?

Comment: @tsturzl FYI, that file is from Bootstrap, I didn't create that. I think it requires me to do further setup before I could use that.

Comment: bootstrap is not a node module, it will not load into node. You're trying to cook a thanks giving turkey in a toaster.